# How to control file operations made to a volume in docker?

Tags: docker, filesystems, storage, driver, volume

The situation is that I have a user space file system which can provide a bunch of posix like interface in user space. Like this:

```
open
read 
write 
mkdir
...
```

I want to make a volume on this file system and pass it to a docker. My question is how can I control the way docker access this volume so that it can be redirected to my posix like interface?
Right now my file system can't be mounted on the host. It is a completely user space file system.
I think fuse can support this, but I don't want to go there unless I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a volume here. If you can access your POSIX interfaces from your application running in docker. You access it and perform read, write etc operations. 
 If you really need a volume implementation, you need to store it into another volume and have a watch dog app sync the changes to your user file system

Comment: thanks for your answer, maybe i wasn't clear, application in docker can only operate on a given path, changing all applications in docker may not be posible and economical.the reson i choose docker is to support as many application as posible, i thought if i can control the way docker operate volume and redirect to my interface, it may be easier.

Comment: True. I understand your point. But there are always solutions which you can build into. My idea would be to implement one container thats common to all of your app containers. This container is a bidirectional implementation where it accepts volume requests from all your apps, and converts them into your POSIX call and gets the return and serves back to your app containers.

Comment: thank you, another container ... en , i think i can live with that, but my question remains, which i don't know how to control the way a docker access a volume, to be clear, i don't know how to control the way a docker access a volume  in that docker or outside from that docker (ie. host side)

Comment: How docker handles volumes with containers. Certainly a book should help you out. You need to reads on Volumes, Bindmounts and tmpfs mounting. Docker In Action must help out. To give a hint, when you map a volume, docker stores these files in its volume store, when you use bind mount, you can bind any of your directory as volume data to your container.

Comment: i tried volume driver but in the end i reliazed that volume driver can only control the way docker handle volume itself, but not the docker handle files or directories in it, are u implying that i can achieve this by change docker itself and recompile it?

Comment: Read operations, bind mount a directory as readonly, write operations, bind mount another directory with write permissions. This way you have your readonly and write operations channelled. Now its upto you how to sync these changes to your user's drive

Comment: i don't what too many data copy or performance penalty, what i want to do is to find a way to hook all file system operation made to a volume and redirect them to my interface.i'm hoping anyone can tell where to look or what part of docker's code i should rewrite if not too difficult

Comment: Great.  I believe you must implement on Linux.  With disc operations.  Intercept them and handle it.  Let us know once you find a solution here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Docker does not implement any file or directory access. It's simply not what docker does, as a matter of design.

All docker does when launching a container is to create a bunch of mounts in such a way that the processes inside the container can issue their regular POSIX calls. When a process inside a container calls `write()`, the call goes directly to the Linux kernel, without docker's knowledge or intervention.

Now, there's a missing piece in your puzzle that has to be implemented one way or another: The application calls e.g. POSIX `write()` function, and your filesystem is not able to intercept this `write()` function.

So you have a couple of options:

**Option 1**: Implement your userspace filesystem in a library:

1. The library would override the `write()` function.
2. You compile the library and put it in some directory e.g. `/build/artifacts/filesystem.so`.
3. You use that directory as a volume when running the container, e.g. `docker run -v /build/artifacts/filesystem.so:/extralibs/filesystem.so ...`
4. you add this filesystem as a preloaded library: `docker run ... --env LD_PRELOAD=/extralibs/filesystem.so ...`

This will make **all calls in the container** use your library, so it should forward all the irrelevant files (e.g. `/bin/bash`, `/etc/passwd` etc.) to the real filesystem.

If you have control over the images, then you can set it up such that only particular commands execute with this `LD_PRELOAD`.

Fair warning: implementing a library which overrides system calls and libc has a lot of pitfalls that you'll need to work around. One example is that if the program uses e.g. `fprintf()`, then you have to override `fprintf()` as well, even though `fprintf()` calls `write()`.

**Option 2**: Modify the application to just call your filsystem functions.

This is assuming you can modify the application and the docker image.

If your filesystem is a service, run it in the container and issue the appropriate RPCs.

If it needs to be shared with other containers, then the backing store for your filesystem can be a volume.

**Option 3**: Make your userspace filesystem available natively within the container.

Meaning any command can issue a `write()` that goes to the kernel directly, and the kernel redirects it to your filesystem.

This essentially means implementing your filesystem as a fuse daemon, mounting it on the host (seeing how you can't mount it inside containers), and using it as a docker volume.

If there's a specific limitation that you're not allowed to mount your filesystem on the host, then you have a lot of work to do to make option 1 work. Otherwise I would advise you to implement your filesystem with fuse and mount it on the host - it has the highest ROI.

Comment: To be precise, it won't work if the executable is statically linked with the C library.